# Can I use only buses in Paris instead of the Métro?

Tags: public-transport, safety, health, buses, paris

I have 4-5 hours between my flight from Amsterdam (Orly airport) and train back to Amsterdam (a one-day trip to Paris). My point is to see the city. I have panic attacks on subways so I avoid them.

Is it possible to see the Eiffel Tower and Champs-Élysées for a bit, then head to Gare du Nord?

I know the Métro is faster and all, but I want a pleasant trip, not panicky. I will not go up the Eiffel Tower, I will just walk in the park in front of it and take a photograph or two. I just want to experience the city for a while.

Comment: No, just see it and take a photo from the ground. :)

Comment: In general, yes, you can make your way around Paris using only overground transportation (buses and tramways). Whether that works out for your particular case is another question, and probably off-topic.

Comment: The OrlyBus (at 8 Euro it's quite expensive but at least it's easy).

Comment: is overground subway okay?

Comment: @fkraiem Why would this be off-topic? Seems quite specific and answerable to me.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: I would upvote that comment several times if I could. Especially with considerable parts of Paris's inner-city metros being [overground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MP73_RATP_Rolling_stock.jpg), this question has traces of an X-Y-problem in it.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Best way to avoid claustrophobia is to [train surf as locals do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9TmX-mDYJU).

Comment: @jpatokal To me it would fall under "questions covering tasks normally performed by travel agents such as constructing travel and tour itineraries."

Comment: Don't forget you can also rent a v'lib. It's cheap and the process si fast and easy.

Comment: @fkraiem The OP has given us their itinerary, they're asking if it's physically possible, for which question I'd trust TravelSE over a travel agent any day.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt claustrophobia is only one of several possible causes for panic attacks. Train surfing is perhaps more likely to induce panic than riding the train properly; at least, the chance of being killed is far higher.

Comment: I would use a velib (bike to rent) if youre physically able/confident, these are like Boris bikes, they cost 1.70 for the day and are faster, greener and a better way to view the city...  You might even get a chance to shoot over to notre dame! http://en.velib.paris.fr/

Answer (score 10):

[Orlybus](http://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-orly/public-transport) departs every 15 - 20 minutes during the day and takes around 30 minutes to arrive at Denfert-Rochereau. So say an hour to get to the terminus. From near there a bus (28) runs to École Militaire, so maybe a short walk and at the Tour Eiffel within 1½ hours.

[image: Paris walk]

About one hour on foot from there to the Place de la Concorde via Arc de Triomphe and Champs-Élysées. From there there is a bus (42) to Gare du Nord, say about ¾ hour (that is enough time to *walk* between the two, but you might have had enough time on foot by then).

In all round about 3¼ hours even allowing for some long wait between services. So plenty of margin for the vagaries of traffic.

Comment: Sometimes the buses in Paris are so slow that walking is faster and they do have a tendency to go out of service when you are in them. So do take your time to travel back to Gare du Nord.

Comment: *Parisienne traffic* => traffic is masculine in French (why not?), unlike English in French adjectives derived from noun shed the capital letter, and this adjective is more naturally placed after the noun (some adjectives go before, some after, ... sorry :/). Anyway, I would advise *traffic parisien*.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are already in central Paris, yes, you can navigate the city by bus only.  To be clear, I recall riding only one bus in Paris years ago.

Like many metro focused cities, the Bus tends to be a longer transit time due to traffic, connections, etc.

You can find a bus map here:  [Paris Bus Service](http://www.ratp.fr/informer/pdf/orienter/f_plan.php?loc=reseaux&nompdf=bus_paris&fm=gif)

4 hours to see a city by Bus is not very long and your biggest challenge might be getting from where the OrlyBus terminates to something worth seeing.  Be ready to hire a Cab or Uber if you start to run short of time.

Answer (score -1):

I have done it once, you will also be able to walk that long only if you have been used to walk. Otherwise looks reasonably dubious.

Good luck